# How to take a valid sublist in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, sublist

I have this weird (I think) problem in Java.
I have an ArrayList and I want to take a sublist.
But I get the follow exception.

```
package javatest;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class JavaTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> alist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        alist.add(10);
        alist.add(20);
        alist.add(30);
        alist.add(40);
        alist.add(50);
        alist.add(60);
        alist.add(70);
        alist.add(80);
        ArrayList<Integer> sub = (ArrayList<Integer>) alist.subList(2, 4);
        for (Integer i : sub)
            System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

> run: Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.util.RandomAccessSubList cannot
>   be cast to java.util.ArrayList    at
>   javatest.JavaTest.main(JavaTest.java:17)
>   Java Result: 1

What is the correct way to take a sublist?

Thx

Comment: Stick to the interface list not the Implementation and you will be fine.Check answer by zeropage.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should work with the interfaces for Collections wherever possible.  You're downcasting the result of sublist, but the API specifies that it returns `List` (**not** `ArrayList`).  Here, the implementors are choosing to return a different type to make their lives easier.

Furthemore, the API documentation specifies that sublist will return a List mapped onto the original, so beware!

Comment: I just expected that a sublist of FooList will also be a FooList. I think it's the reasonable thing to think. Anyways thx :)

Answer (score 46):

make it as :

```
List sublist = new ArrayList();
sublist = new ArrayList<String>(alist.subList(2, 4));
```

and it should work

Comment: This is very incorrect. The first line has absolutely no effect. It creates a new Array list which is just orphaned on the next line when a new ArraysList<String> is created. The new ArrayList is initialized with the values returned from alist.subList. But this is very different than alist.subList which is backed by alist.

Answer (score 8):

Try this...

```
List<Integer> alist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
alist.add(10);
alist.add(20);
alist.add(30);
alist.add(40);
alist.add(50);
alist.add(60);
alist.add(70);
alist.add(80);
List<Integer> sub = alist.subList(2, 4);
for (Integer i : sub)
  System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
List<Integer> sub = alist.subList(2, 4);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    public List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
    return (this instanceof RandomAccess ?
            new RandomAccessSubList<E>(this, fromIndex, toIndex) :
            new SubList<E>(this, fromIndex, toIndex));
    }
```

like at the ArrayList's impl, it is return List,as @George Kastrinis said use 
interface wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to:

```
List<Integer> sub = alist.subList(2, 4);
```

The `sublist()` method returns a `List`, which not necessarily is an `ArrayList` (here it's actually a `RandomAccessSublist`, which is why the cast fails).